# Firefox can't load temporary addon: Error: Can't find profile directory

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm starting to work on a small firefox plugin, it's a basic js script, no problem on this side.

I've made a few successfull tests, and had a a few satisfying results. But starting yesterday, i'm unable to laod any temporary addons in firefox.
Everytime i try to start one (even a simple console.log("hello world")), i get the error message in the console:

```
Error: Can't find profile directory. XULStore.jsm:66:15
```

It work perfectly 2 days ago, the problem appeared yesterday, and, as far as i know, i didn't made any firefox upgrade.

I've made a few reseach, a found two usefull links, one on discourse.mozilla of someone that has the exact same problem ... but no answer, and another one on bugzilla saying this bug won't be fixed because it should last long ... https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1548017

I'm askign here because i can't find any solution to my problem, and right now, it's been 24h since i'm stuck in my development progress. I'm open to any suggestion that might work.

- I've checked my profiles directory and files, they're existing and ok... and that's basically everything. I'm not familiiar with the tools available for firefox so, i might have forgotten to check basic things that might help.

***P.S:*** i'm not using selenium at any time (i've seen a few requests here about a similar issue with selenium, but i'm writing vanilla JS here, so, i think it's not the same issue)

Comment: How do you load the addon in Firefox? Are you using the `web-ext` [CLI](https://github.com/mozilla/web-ext)?

Comment: To be honest i give up this, and resigned to use the TamperMonkey extension ... that's a shame, but i had to make it work.
I don't really remember how i used to made this

Comment: See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1661906

Comment: I faced the same problem. It's sad that the basic tutorial itself doesn't work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension